# sqlalchemy / flask: run a job with an additional insert/update commit after initial insert // @event.listens_for(Request, "after_insert")

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a backend using flask / sqlalchemy that inserts records into a table ("Requests").
After the insert, I want to run additional jobs in the backend, whereby additional updates the table should happen.

Example: Let's say I insert 3 records, and commit them, the "after_insert" will pick the 3 newly created id's up. I now want to run each of those id's through a specific backend function, which will further update the table (here the function 'run_backend_job').

The problem I currently have is that sqlalchemy keeps complaining as below, and I was not able to figure out how to get around it.

I have been looking into creating a new session for the second commit, but was not able to get it to work (and also not sure if it's the right direction to address this).

Any pointer would be appreciated.

**Error:**

> An error occurred: Method 'commit()' can't be called here; method
> '_prepare_impl()' is already in progress and this would cause an
> unexpected state change to <SessionTransactionState.CLOSED: 5>
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/isce)

**Code:**

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy import event, func, inspect
# from flask_socketio import emit
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Request(db.Model):
    id: str = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    request_text: str = db.Column(db.String(400))  
    folder       : str = db.Column(db.String(400))       
    filename     : str = db.Column(db.String(400))          
    status       : str = db.Column(db.String(400))   
    added_from   : str = db.Column(db.String(400))  
    added_date   : str = db.Column(db.String(400))      
    updated_date : str = db.Column(db.String(400)) 

@event.listens_for(Request, "after_insert")
def emit_request_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    item_inserted = target.id
    # do some other stuff
    # emit('item_inserted', item_inserted, broadcast=True)
    # emit('counts_updated', broadcast=True)
    run_backend_job(target.id, target.request_text)


############  HANDLING OF JOBS ############

def current_time():
    return datetime.now(ZoneInfo('Europe/Zurich')).strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

def run_backend_job(id, request_text):   
    time = current_time()
    try:  
        folder, filename = get_folder_filename(request_text)
        row = Request.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        row.updated_date = current_time()
        row.folder = folder
        row.filename = filename   
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception as error:
        print("An error occurred:", error)
    return


def get_folder_filename(request_text):
    return ('/somepath/','somefilename.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

The general consensus is to avoid event listeners at all costs. They are notoriously brittle and make business logic hard to follow. This could be refactored into a simpler utility function you use for creating Requests for example. Some pseudo code is below to give you an idea.

```
def create_request(**kwargs):
    request = Request(**kwargs)
    folder, filename = get_folder_filename(request_text)
    request.updated_date = current_time()
    request.folder = folder
    request.filename = filename   
    db.session.add(request)
```

As a side note you probably want to use date columns for the dates.

Comment: Thank you, for the pointers, I'll study them in more detail later today. Re date column - I am using a sqllite db, my understanding is that they don't support date columns..

Comment: Hi Daniel, the reason I had planned using events is because I want the record to be created instantly, so that the user that triggers the creation via a UI gets the response "yep, record created" and can move on. The record needs to have more info then, which the backend can independently look up and enrich the record with (which will take time). Thus I had planned doing the return to the user after the commit, and using the "after-insert" to populate the rest. How would you solve that?

Comment: AFAIK the event listeners are all firing in the same thread so this would all be happening before the function returns to the user anyhow. If you have expensive work that need to happen asynchronously you’ll want to set up something like celery and run a background task.

Comment: You can test the theory by putting a time.sleep(10) in the event listener.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Let me check out celery. Just so I don‘t start going down a rabbit‘s hole; to pass a job to celery I guess I need to pass the ID of the newly inserted records. Since that is an autoincrement key I don‘t know it pre-commit. Is my understanding correct and you would use the „after-insert“ event (where we have the ID) to then create the celery job? Or do you see a way to get it in the function that calls the commit to then directly create the job from there?

Comment: If you call db.session.flush it will pull an id and set it on the object. No events required.

Comment: Thanks @daniel tiesling, this worked like a charm!