# Flask SQL Alchemy: Object.query.all() does not show newly inserted records in @event.listens_for(Object, "after_insert")

Tags: sqlite, events, sqlalchemy, event-handling, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask sqlalchemy and want to run a bunch of backend operations after new records have been added to a table.

What I struggle with is that the event that registers the newly added records does not return those records when querying the table.

In below example (not working code, gathered from different places in my app - but the principle is the same), I add a line to an existing model.

The "after-insert" picks this event up, and fires the "do_some_background_job" task. So far, so good.

What happens then is weird. Querying the object in it's entirety shows all records, but the ones that were freshly added. If there were 10 records before, and I just added a new one, then the count of records from the table shows still 10, and the target.id (that is received from the after-insert event) even says there should be 11.

Any ideas how I can actually get what is now in the table? The changes have been committed..

P.S. if there is a better way for my application to run backend jobs when the DB table changes, happy to learn about it.. I thought using the events would be the most suitable place to do it.

```
from .. import engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
session_factory = sessionmaker(engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

from app import db
from sqlalchemy import event
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict


# Adds a new line
this_session = Session()
this_session.add(Request(request_text='abc', folder='somefolder',filename='somefile', status='somestatus'))
this_session.commit()

@dataclass
class Request(db.Model):
    id: str = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    request_text: str = db.Column(db.String(400))  
    folder       : str = db.Column(db.String(400))       
    filename     : str = db.Column(db.String(400))          
    status       : str = db.Column(db.String(400))   


@event.listens_for(Request, "after_insert")
def emit_request_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    do_some_background_job(target.id)

def do_some_background_job(id, request_text):   
    # Do some background job
    res = Request.query.all()
    request_list = [asdict(x) for x in res]
    print(id)                   # Shows the id of the newest item (say, 11)
    print(len(request_list))    # Shows the count previous to the insert (say 10) - Why not 11?!
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem for myself by using a different approach; rather than using "after-insert" events, I am using celery tasks now.

The tips relevant for my solution I received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77576987/sqlalchemy-flask-run-a-job-with-an-additional-insert-update-commit-after-init) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77605534/db-session-commit-inside-celery-task-outside-of-request-context).