# db.session.commit inside celery task: "Outside of request context"

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to use celery to modify an SQLalchemy table.
The task correctly prints into the console the target record, but upon committing I get the below error.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Many thanks for your pointers.

> [2023-12-05 11:23:21,575: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] An error occurred:
>
> [2023-12-05 11:23:21,575: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] Working outside of
> request context.
>
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that
> needed an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing
> for information about how to avoid this problem.

Here is my celery task:

```
@celery.task
def background_job(id, request_text):  
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    with app.app_context():
        try:  
            row = Request.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
            row.request_text = request_text
            print(row)              # WORKS -> Shows the new data in the row
            db.session.commit()     # FAILS -> See error above
        except Exception as error:
            print("An error occurred:", error)
    return
```

Here is my celery_worker script:

```
#!/bin/env python
import os
from app import celery, create_app

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
app.app_context().push()
```

and here is my main app:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from celery import Celery

socketio = SocketIO()
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

celery = Celery(    __name__, 
                    broker=Config.broker_url, 
                    include=Config.include, 
                    broker_connection_retry_on_startup = Config.broker_connection_retry_on_startup)


def create_app(debug=False):
    """Create an application."""
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    # API Endpoints
    from .endpoints_rest import endpoints_rest as blueprint_endpoints_rest
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint_endpoints_rest)
    from .endpoints_socketio import endpoints_socketio as blueprint_endpoints_socketio
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint_endpoints_socketio) 

    socketio.init_app(app)

    return app
```

Debug-Logs of celery worker (without print(row)):
https://pastebin.com/A9mMWsey

Full Error (without the try / except):
https://pastebin.com/8Td0SpHn

Comment: This will not work. Keep in mind that Celery is distributed. The session may not even be created on some workers that may take the task to run. So, instead of doing what you plan to do, create session inside the task, and do necessary DB changes there.

Comment: Please add the complete error, including stack trace.

Comment: hi @MiguelGrinberg, I executed the worker with loglevel =debug and pasted the respective logs into pastebin (added at the end of my original post). I also removed the "try/except" and added a pastebin link with the full error. Is this what you meant with stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

In line 44 of models.py you have a Socket.IO emit:

```
emit('item_updated', update, broadcast=True)
```

This is in a function that is a SQLAlchemy event handler, triggered automatically when you issue the commit in the background job.

The issue is that the `emit()` function from Flask-SocketIO tries to determine the namespace under which to issue the notification from the request context, because you did not indicate what the namespace should be. I think if you make this explicit the error will go away:

```
emit('item_updated', update, namespace='/', broadcast=True)
```

Comment: you are a hero! I would NEVER have figured it out! thank you 1 million times!